# separating a substring of pattern of string

Tags: java, string

I am designing a program in which user enters a string that have a specific pattern of three `"has"` but characters between `"has"` can change. For example, user can enter string like `"iihasiiaahasiihas"` or `"iihasiaaahasiaaahas"`.

I'm using this code to separate substring containing `"has"`:

```
    int va= sr.indexOf("has");
    int va2=sr.lastIndexOf("has");
    String s1=sr.substring(va, va2+3);
```

But my problem is that if user entered string contain one or two `"has"` it will also separate substring.

I want that substring which contain three `"has"` and I can't use compare method because I do not know the characters which user will enter between three `"has"`. So can anyone give me suggestion that what shall I do?

Output should be like this:

`"hasiiaahasiihas"` for `string1` and `"hasiaaahasiaaahas"` for another `string`.

In between character between three `"has"` can change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a regex:
`"has.*?has.*?has"`

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("has.*?has.*?has");
Matcher m = p.matcher(inputString);
while(m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Comment: This seems more like what Sarah actually wants to do.

Comment: I was going to say use var n=str.match(/has.+has.+has/); Upvoted your answer

Comment: @WindsorAndy One thing to note: the regex you would propose uses a greedy quantifier `+` rather than reluctant quantifier `+?`.
For a string `"hasxhasxhasxhas"`, your regex `has.+has.+has` would match whole string, but mine matches first 3 `has`. In other words without reluctant quantifiers you'll get the longest possible match.

Answer (score 1):

Use split method to split each word and to get the array of words separated by keyword 'has':

```
sr.split("has")
```

Comment: I don't think you're understanding what she wants to do. She wants has to function as a start and end tag, but not pickup the has values in the middle.

Comment: This is a regex problem. With split you're left with results that need further processing even to check they're a valid hit